# write an "operating system" that dims Num Lock

Tags: popularity-contest, assembly, machine-code

I want to write x86 assembler code that can be used to boot your computer from and dims NumLock. This means

- you cannot rely on glibc or any other of these "comfi" libraries
- you cannot rely on the Linux kernel
- we will test your code by dumping it onto a virtual floppy and boot a VM from it
- goal is to switch on and off NumLock so quickly that it appears dimmed
- it's okay if everything fits into the bootloader and loops endlessly

Solution with most votes wins.

Comment: I know you __think__ "dim numlock - that's easy" but it is not. So much has to happen to get that far, like scanning for devices and drivers for them. A PS2 keyboard might be easier but I digress. I could make a z80 output "Hello world!" via a UART easily though :P

Comment: wow good comment... I did dim NumLock once and thought I knew it was easy. But that was maybe specific to my DIN keyboard (DIN was the predecessor for PS/2 at least in Germany).

Comment: doesn't the BIOS give you an address where to write the NumLock? If not, how would you do it e.g. in the boot loader? Now I am curious to solve my own excercise :)

Comment: use port 60: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434827/assembly-keyboard-io-port

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested this (VirtualBox doesn't pass through its virtual keyboard LEDs onto the physical keyboard, and I'm not on a PC I can reboot currently). But I think it should probably work and is probably quite minimal.

There may be [some additional setup](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH20/CH20-2.html) that needs to be done on the keyboard controller for these commands to work. If so it would be essentially trivial to add to the code below...

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
mov al, 0xed
out 0x60, al
mov al, 0x07
out 0x60, al
mov al, 0xed
out 0x60, al
mov al, 0x00
out 0x60, al
jmp $$
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Compile with `nasm -f bin -o floppy.img numlock.asm`.

Will give this a real test and tweak accordingly later (if someone else wants to try and/or tweak it feel free).

Comment: works on my laptop. My laptop's numlock goes on an off.  No external keyboard needed. Also scroll lock and caps lock. Good trick with times 510 - ...